# Creating mixed components in swing + java

Tags: java, swing, custom-component

Is there any way to create a custom component in swing. By custom I mean say right now I am able to create a circle and do actions like dragging it etc.

But now I also want that along with the circle a text label with its number is also present. Can we combine them into a new type of component where say we can do actions on it collectively?

If yes please give me pointers on how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just extend `JComponent` and handle painting and interaction however you want.  If there is a component that already does most of what you want you could extend that class and tweak it slightly.

I would suggest reading some of the tutorials about how JComponent works:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/jcomponent.html

Here is a similar question but I am sure you can find more specific ones that have been asked once you get deeper into it.
[How to create a custom Swing Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822899/how-to-create-a-custom-swing-component)

The Swing tutorial as a whole if very useful to understand how other components work etc.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html

Comment: Like I want to have a label associated with a circle then for that too I would need to extend jcomponent ??? Or is there any other method??

Comment: @user, yes, no other method.   (As a side note, you don't need to repeat punctuation marks)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Swing component extending `JComponent`. Several question here on Stack on the topic like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822899/how-to-create-a-custom-swing-component).
Personally, I advise you to get this book: [Java Swing](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596004088) as it contains an excellent guide on how to create Swing components.