# Creating a tab bar with Swing

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I want to make this kind of look and feel

[image]

The buttons on the menu (dashboard, my items, catalog).
Is it possible to make that on swing? or what kind of component is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [JTabbedPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html):

[image]

Here's a [tutorial](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/22/how-to-write-custom-swing-component.html) and an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822899/how-to-create-a-custom-swing-component) about customizing Swing components.