# how to make Indeterminate progressbar look nicely?

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, jprogressbar, nimbus

I'm using nimbus lookAndFill

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
```

and my indeterminate JProgressBar looks like that:

http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/9470/uglyprogress.jpg

can i make it looks better?

Comment: You could write your own UI delegate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an easier solution. You can just copy the progress bar UI defaults before setting the nimbus look-and-feel and then set them back after. You then get Nimbus look and feel but without its progress bar styling.

```
// copy progress bar defaults
HashMap<Object, Object> progressDefaults = new HashMap<>();
for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : UIManager.getDefaults().entrySet()){
    if(entry.getKey().getClass() == String.class && ((String)entry.getKey()).startsWith("ProgressBar")){
        progressDefaults.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}

// set nimbus
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");

// copy back progress bar defaults
for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : progressDefaults.entrySet()){
    UIManager.getDefaults().put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: I found the best solution, based on your!

*//setting NimbusLookAndFeel*
<br>
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NimbusLookAndFeel());


*// setting other progress bar l&f*
<br>
processingJProgressBar.**setUI**(new WebProgressBarUI());

Answer (score 2):

You can either [use a different look and fill](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) or [create your own component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822899/how-to-create-a-custom-swing-component).

Comment: Just wanted to keep this l&F, but use another for progress bar

Comment: Philip's answer will do it, I didn't think of that, its a much simpler solution too