# Java Swing Component Development

Tags: java, swing

i've been looking around at custom component development, i found a few things.
[How to create a custom Swing Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822899/how-to-create-a-custom-swing-component)

After i came across this I figured i'd go download the source and look through it. the only problem is i'm having quite the time trying to find anything at all. I want to find the JLabel and JButton classes like suggested in the linked post but I do not know where to find anything. I've been searching folder after folder.

This is the download i have. [Source from OpenJDK](https://jdk7.java.net/source.html)

Comment: If you have the JDK installed, there should be a `src.zip` file contained within it, which contains most of the `.java` source...

Comment: I've downloaded the Java Platform (JDK) 7u45 from Oracle, i'm not seeing any src.zip

Comment: False alarm I found it. I didn't see it at the bottom of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open src.zip (it's in your jdk home) then follow package name as directory path:

```
javax/swing/JLabel.java
javax.swing/JButton.java
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew to follow the path i just couldn't find the src folder