# Database Modeling Gui in java

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I want to make a user interface in Java for database modeling, like the image below.

I have made tables but they are not re-sizeable, they only show column using JTable and JFrame.  Am I doing right or there any better way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Seems like a lot of work. What have you done so far?

Comment: i make tables but they are not re-sizeable, they only show column using JTable and Jframe but i m not conform, am i doing right or there any better way to do this ?

Comment: @PeterPenzov is there any good helping link for Swing custom Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you can nest Swing components inside of a JPanel to create your database table component.

```
JPanel
    JLabel
    JScrollPane
        JTree
    JScrollPane
        JList
```

This may or may not be easier than creating a custom Swing component.

You will definitely want to create a GUI model that combines the DefaultMutableTreeNodes of the JTree and the DefaultListModel of the JList.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make Swing custom component - it's a lot of work.

More information: [How to create a custom Swing Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822899/how-to-create-a-custom-swing-component)